# How do I get just the filename and just the path separately in a DragDrop in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

Title says it all. I just need to get the File's name that is dragged into the form by itself and the file's path (without name) into separate variables.

Code:

```
Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    Dim theFiles() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData("FileDrop", True), String())
    Dim tep As Integer = 0
    For Each path As String In files
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then

            ' Assign the files to an array.
            Dim MyFiles As String() = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

            ' Display the file Name
            MessageBox.Show(MyFiles(tep))
            tep += 1
        End If
    Next
```

It gives me the path WITH the name from "MessageBox.show(MyFiles(tep))". I don't want that. I only want the path. I also do want the name, but just not with the path. I want them separate.

Comment: Code would be a good start we are not mind readers. Please update post with related code that's not working and where you are stuck. Im 110% positive we can help if you help us in providing code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `System.IO` namespace to separate your path and file name.

The `Path.GetDirectoryName()` method will give you the parent directory's path of the specified file or directory, and the `Path.GetFileName()` method will give you the name and extension of the specified file.

```
Dim FilePath As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(MyFiles(tep))
Dim FileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(MyFiles(tep))

MessageBox.Show(FilePath)
MessageBox.Show(FileName)
```

The code will produce for example:

`C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop`

and

`Open me.txt`

---

**Read more:**

[MSDN - Path.GetDirectoryName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN - Path.GetFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ah, that did it! Fantastic! Thank you so much!